# Force redundant name qualifier for static methods in Resharper

Tags: c#, resharper

I know I can force "this." qualifier for instance member with Resharper code cleanup.

Can I force redundant name qualifier for static methods?

```
public class Foo
{
    public void Bar()
    {
        StaticMethod();
    }

    private static void StaticMethod()
    {

    }
}
```

Would be forced to this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public void Bar()
    {
        Foo.StaticMethod();
    }

    private static void StaticMethod()
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see any way to do this in ReSharper 5.x, and have seen nothing about it in 6.x EAP/Beta releases, but don't have an instance of 6.x to verify.

You could suggest it as a feature in JetBrains' issue tracker: http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+Issue+Tracker

Comment: Posted it as http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-273447 . Please vote for it if you need it.

Comment: According to the tracker this is fixed in v8, but I can't find any options related to it in v10...